# Azure Cloud service continuous deployment service configuration

Tags: git, azure, tfs, msbuild

How does one select the service configuration or publish profile for an Azure cloud service continuous deployment build configuration?

I have solution "A" in a TFS git repo. I also have a cloud service "B" in Azure with continues integration/delivery/deployment setup to deploy after a push to the master branch. This works perfectly for my production environment.

I am now trying to setup a testing/qualifying environment. For this I have created cloud service "C" and set up continues integration with TFS to redeploy solution "A" every time I push to the EDGE branch. This works fine, except it uses the CLOUD service configuration, instead of my "testing" service configuration. I suspect it is a setting in the build configuration of the cloud service "C" that is not specified and thus it just uses the default.

Before some genius suggests I use the production staging environment for testing, here is my response: The staging environment is meant to be an exact copy of production with the idea of being able to just swop a new deployment onto production to minimize the downtime. I need a testing environment with a unique URL, using another database and having different settings specified in my Testing.cscfg file.

Is it perhaps an extra MSBuild argument that I need to specify?

Please answer with exact steps of how to configure this type of setup, or if I'm approaching the whole situation wrong, please feel free to tell me I'm being an idiot (with the correct answer off course).

http://grab.by/Boyw

http://grab.by/Boyy

Comment: I fear that there is no good solution for this. You can however customize the build template to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Just add "/p:TargetProfile=Testing" in the MSBuild arguments section (Edit build definition > Process > 2. Build > 5. Advanced)

Comment: There doesn't work for me.  Are you using the `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml` build template?